# How to set aggregate limit in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to set the limit for sensordatas table. I need only 5 elements from the lookup.
What I found in the doc is [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-limit), but not sure how to use it.

```
Sensor.aggregate({
    $lookup: {
        from: "sensordatas",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "sensor",
        as: "data"
    }
}).exec(function (err, docs) {
    res.json({ data: docs, err: err });
});
```

For know i found the following solution, the new problem is that i need to sort it before it sliced.

```
Sensor.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "sensordatas",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "sensor",
        as: "data"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1, name: 1, notify: 1, updated_at: 1, data: { "$slice": ["$data", -1] },
    }
}]).exec(function (err, docs) {
    res.json({ data: docs, err: err });
});
```

Comment: Limit by what? The first 5 in the `"data"` array returned by each lookup?

Comment: Then add it as an answer instead. Especially since someone else added an answer that is incorrect.